# Equivalent of bivariate Fourier series with polynomial denominator

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

My goal is to have an equivalent, as $t\to \infty$, of
$$\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^2,m\neq 0}\frac{1}{\|m\|^\alpha}\exp(im\cdot u/t)\exp(-(m/t)^2)$$ for $u\in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Does anyone recognize something? I am overall interested by the case $\alpha=2$.

I tried the Poisson summation formula but the involved function is not integrable so the result does not make any sense (to me). I am equivalently interested by teplacing the Gauss kernel with a truncation at $m=t$ .

Another successful approach would be to understand the behaviour of
$$\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^2,m\neq 0}\frac{1}{\|m\|^2}\exp(im\cdot u)$$ for small $u$, but then one has still to understand the error wrt the first sum.

They don't seem like such unlikely expressions to occur, but I have scrolled some book of "special functions" with many ugly expressions but never found something under this form. Any clue regarding one of these expressions will definitely help me!